Mongoose findOne always return null
This is the user snippet


const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  userType: { type: String, required: true },
  workplaces: { type: [Number], required: true },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'users');

module.exports = User;



This is the code that i have


const accountExists = await User.findOne({ email: extractData.email})
console.log(accountExists);



If the email that the user has entered exists in the db there should be an error but the findOne always return null even if there is a user with the same email

That duplicate key error is occurring on the insert, not the findOne.  Try also logging extractData.email to that console.log to make sure you are searching for what you think you are.

This question is similar to: E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Check the input you are passing before findOne like :
const emailToCheck = extractData.email.trim().toLowerCase();
const accountExists = await User.findOne({ email: emailToCheck });
console.log(accountExists);


Error while creating a new user It says, the error is coming while creating new user.
Because there is already a user with same identity.

Based on the error it means that the user isn't saved, because that user is already stored in the database. so in your insert controller try to make a condition and first try to extract properties from object that you send to you database:
For example :
{username , email ,password } = req.body;

And use this approach instead:
// Check if we have the same userEmail that the user entered in our database:
const userEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

// If it exists we send this error to him:
if (userEmail) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: "email already exists" });
}

